# Where is the glowing tree in the Scarlet Pillars?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-4

I'm trying to do the quest "Slime mold of the gods" and think I've mapped all of the Scarlet Pillars, but apparently not because I can't find the glowing tree described in the quest. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that I was searching during the day. To find the glowing tree, you have to search the Scarlet Pillars at night so you can see the glow.

The tree area in question is right around B1-B2. There are 9 trees that glow either red, golden, azure, or white. You only care about the one that glows white, so once you identify it, mark it on your map so that you can point it out to the Duke afterwards.